# User saves a Record which meets Apex criteria to Delete the Record, resulting in "Record deleted" page - can I bypass this page?

Tags: apex, redirect, delete

This is a long shot, as I've already gone a fair bit of googling, but wanted to check with the Stack community to cover all my bases.

> **Scenario:** Our reps sometimes have to 'Cancel' events and remove them
>   from their Calendar, and sometimes other users (front desk) need to
>   cancel events for anyone in the business, on behalf of the customer if
>   they call to cancel.
>
> We also want to track Cancellation History for
>   each account, and allow for people to cancel for one another - so we
>   can't use the normal delete button due to Role Hierarchy security
>   getting in the way of people deleting for other people.

So, I built an Apex trigger and class method that checks to see when
the status of an Event is first set to "Cancelled" (after update), and
then it copies/inserts all relevant Event data into a custom object
called Cancellation_History__c and deletes the Event that was just
marked as "Cancelled".

> **Problem/Question:** When a user edits the Event record and marks it as "Cancelled", obviously that triggers the Apex which, in turn,
>   deletes the Event record that was just modified. Since the user just
>   saved/updated that record, Salesforce standard behavior wants to
>   redirect them to the record that they just updated. However, Apex has
>   already deleted that record, which results in the user reaching the
>   "Record Deleted" page.
>
> Can I somehow improve this user experience, by rerouting them
>   programmatically to the account page instead of the standard behavior
>   of trying to load the record that was just deleted?

I'm happy to provide code if requested, but I don't think it is relevant to the question itself so I excluded it. We currently use standard Salesforce page layouts (not VisualForce pages), but if there is a solution that exists through VisualForce I'd be happy to hear it also.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you ever try any of the recommended strategies?

Comment: Hey @AdrianLarson, sorry for the delay - I haven't yet tried actually. I was in the Salesforce DEV450 training class all last week so I haven't had a chance. I like your solution tho, it looks elegant. I'll test it today or tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Don't forget, if you think the answer is useful, even if you do not adopt the recommended approach, you can vote for it. :) Up-votes don't commit you to accept the answer or follow through with the recommendation therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to override the `View` action so that when you get a deleted record, you redirect to the home page, otherwise, go to the normal detail page. This approach may be less intrusive to your users' workflow than having a separate edit process when they wish to cancel.

**Page**

```
<apex:page
    standardController="Event"
    extensions="EventViewExtension"
    action="{!redirect}" />
```

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class EventViewExtension
{
    final Id recordId;
    final PageReference view;
    public EventViewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        recordId = controller.getId();
        view = controller.view();
        view.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    }
    public PageReference redirect()
    {
        List<Event> records = [
            SELECT IsDeleted, AccountId FROM Event
            WHERE Id = :recordId ALL ROWS
        ];

        if (records.isEmpty()) return new PageReference('/');

        if (!records[0].IsDeleted) return view;

        return new ApexPages.StandardController(
            new Account(Id=records[0].AccountId)
        ).view();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly Adrian, thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Write a Visualforce page for this. Without getting too intensive, it might look like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="EventCancelExtension">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelEvent}" value="Cancel" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The extension you need would look like:

```
public class EventCancelExtension {
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public EventCancelExtension(ApexPages.StandardController c) {
        controller = c;
    }
    public PageReference cancelEvent() {
        // Do whatever you do here, then:
        return new ApexPages.StandardController(
            new Account(Id=((Event)c.getRecord()).AccountId)).view();
    }
}
```

Feel free to include error handling, a better UX, and so on.